# I am not able to get the result when joining two tables with where clause with OR condition

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables projects and project_user_cross. I want to get the projects if the user id exists in either of the two tables

Here is the `projects` table

```
Id | project_manager_id | name | description | created_at | updated_at | progress
1  | 1                  | p 1  | lorem ipsum | 2019-9-16  |            | 0
```

Here is the `project_user_cross` table (empty)

```
Id | project_id  | user_id
```

Here is the query I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM projects p 
INNER JOIN project_user_cross c ON c.project_id = p.id 
WHERE p.project_manager_id =1 OR c.user_id =1
```

Since project_manager_id = 1 exists I want the query to return the projects but its returning nothing.

Comment: Wow thank you Akina

Comment: I am getting values for all columns except the Id is returning null. Why is that ?

Comment: I am getting null in codeigniter if you can help

Comment: If a project has manager_id = 2 and no users at all, should it be in the results or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> except the Id is returning null

You must obtain 2 columns named `ID`. First - from `projects` table with value of `1`, second - from `project_user_cross` table with value of `NULL`.

To distinguish them you must replace the asterisk with `table.name` fields list and unique aliases when fieldnames are equal (one field may stay unnamed).

```
SELECT p.Id, -- do not rename
       p.project_manager_id, 
       p.name, 
       p.description, 
       p.created_at, 
       p.updated_at, 
       p.progress, 
       c.Id AS crosstab_id, -- rename 
       c.project_id, 
       c.user_id
FROM projects p 
LEFT JOIN project_user_cross c 
   ON c.project_id=p.id 
WHERE p.project_manager_id=1 
   OR (    c.user_id=1 
        OR c.user_id IS NULL )
```

Comment: This will also return projects (with any project manager) that are not associated with any user at all.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I don't know does OP needs in this. If not he will ask later maybe.

Answer (score 1):

The join happens - logically - before the `WHERE` clause is applied. You can use an `EXISTS`, moving the join to a subquery:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM projects  p
WHERE p.project_manager_id = 1
   OR EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM project_user_cross  c
        WHERE c.project_id = p.id 
          AND c.user_id = 1
      ) ;
```